# Where are attached event-handlers 'meta-data' stored? On the "DOM," object, or...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, event-handling, dom-events

I've always wondered... so you have a code like this:

```
$('#click-me');
```

and you attach it with this:

```
$('#click-me').click(someFunction);
```

where is the 'meta-data' that says:

**"Hey "jQuery-object #click-me," I will point you to 'someFunction' when you are clicked!"**

I know that event-handlers can get destroyed such as my situation with Backbone.js where my events stopped firing due to me re-rendering the entire page, destroying some background functions/objects/Views along the way.. *(this is the context as to why I'm asking this question)*

**NOW, MY QUESTION IS**:

**where are events 'meta-data' stored and how are they destroyed?** 
*Are they stored within the function that bound it to a function? Are they within the DOM 'meta-data' (if there is one) itself?*

I'm trying to learn the intricacies of JavaScript because I'm tired of bugs. In addition to that, I'm wondering if I should watch out for garbage collection that might detach my events and such. Coming from C#, I would say JavaScript with the DOM is really something...

(also, as a side note, how can I access these events and 'debug' them? firefox? chrome?)

---

**UPDATE**

**To say it in different words, where is the information that connects a DOM element to a certain event stored? DOM? Objects? (or.. does jQuery map it? does JavaScript have a 'meta-data'?** *it's around that context..*

Comment: I think my post answers both your questions. Tell me if anything isn't clear.

Comment: @gideon please don't edit his anymore because that's exactly what I meant.. see others who answered it.. I'm asking JavaScript & DOM and the 'meta-data' that connects these events, not the codes that jQuery uses to translate to attachEvent or addEventListener.. thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery stores all the event binding and data cache on the jQuery.cache object. All the DOM nodes which were wrapped with jQuery and had events bound to them or data set will get automatically cleared when you are using jQuery `html`, `empty`, `remove`, `replace` etc.

That's why it's very important to never use `innerHTML` or other native DOM methods to insert/replace content that was altered before by jQuery. It will lead to **leaks** that you won't be able to cleanup unless you reset the jQuery.cache object manually.

There is also an undocumented method `jQuery.cleanData` which takes a collection of DOM nodes as an argument and it iterates over them and cleans up all their event bindings, data and removes references to these elements from the cache. This one can be useful if you have DOM fragments which were detached from the main DOM tree and there is a risk that they won't get cleaned up properly.

Comment: you pretty much described what happened to me.. when I did a .html(..), all my events got deleted.. mind if you could clarify this to me or direct me to a resource? you're pretty much right on with your answer here.. but 'where is it stored?' does JS store it in some kind of metadata or does jQuery do the magical storing?

Comment: jQuery does the `magical` storing by putting the handler and all the events boud to it in its internal cache (check in JS console `$.cache`)

Comment: Check jQuery method `_data` (line 1845 in jquery 1.7.1) it's used to retrieve element's meta-data object or sets and then if you check how `data` method works and if you follow event binding methods (`on`, `off`) and go deeper to the non public jQuery.event.add and jQuery.event.remove methods (starts at line 2840) you will see that it uses the `_data` method to get the cache to later set the event handler reference on it and put event callbacks on it

Comment: Hmm.. very interesting.. but with regards to assigning of event in the DOM, JS takes care of that right? Why does jQ's .html() or even .innerHTML() destroy the events? (in a 'get' context). Is it because they just get the 'stringified' version of the elements?

Comment: Yes, in the end jQuery uses DOM events to handle interaction (check lines 2922+) though it does much more then just that as you can see a glimpse of it above. Hope it gives you at least enough to dig deeper in the jquery source code and figure out the details - there is some really smart stuff in there! :)

Answer (score 5):

**Update** : So I misunderstood the question, you wanted to know how events are bound in the context of just javascript and html. My original answer below describes how jquery creates and manages events. It boils down to a call to [element.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener).

From the MDN docs you see the *eventtarget* can be an *element*, the *document*, *window* or an *XMLHttpRequest*.  From the [w3 specifications on DOM Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-registration) an event target adds, removes and dispatches an event. So even information is probably stored in whatever is encapsulating things like elements, this will be **implemented at the browser level.**

From the issue you mentioned about *copying and then replacing the html from the body erases the events*, I'm thinking the browser just gives you the markup (without the event metadata) and then when you replace it, the metadata is gone. ( http://jsfiddle.net/qu9bF/1/)

---

**Original answer**: How jquery event handlers work.

Ok so I started digging this, for JQuery 1.4.2 (because I had to use a couple tools, all of which aren't updated)

Take a look first at this:
http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.4.2&fn=click

```
function (fn) {
    return fn ? this.bind(name, fn) : this.trigger(name);
}
```

That is how click is *defined*, it isn't actually defined in code. JQuery defines this function for all events/handler functions like below, yes! they are *created/defined* dynamically :

```
jQuery.each( ("blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click
            dblclick " +
        "mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave " +
        "change select submit keydown keypress keyup error").split(" "), 
    function( i, name ) {
        // the magic happens here..
        //each string is added as a function to the prototype
        jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( fn ) {
                return fn ? this.bind( name, fn ) : this.trigger( name );
        };//if a handler is NOT specified then attach an event OR call/trigger it

        if ( jQuery.attrFn ) {
                jQuery.attrFn[ name ] = true;
        }
});
```

From here on we need to look at bind, now `bind()` and `one()` are also defined like this. Search for *"Code : bind and one events"* [here](http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/javascript/deconstructed/jquery)

From here I used chrome with this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qu9bF/ to step into the code. The block from `c.each(["bind"` is how the bind function is defined. The source is minified, but [chrome can format it](http://www.andismith.com/blog/2011/11/25-dev-tool-secrets/).

[image]

From here on the code calls `JQuery.events.add`, you can find this under the Events section [here](http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/javascript/deconstructed/jquery). This is **not** the `add()` that is documented I think

Toward the bottom, this piece of code is what does the magic. It accordingly calls [element.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) or [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28VS.85%29.aspx). See how it adds the *on* for `attachEvent`.

```
// Check for a special event handler
// Only use addEventListener/attachEvent if the special
// events handler returns false
if ( !special.setup || 
      special.setup.call( elem, data, namespaces, eventHandle ) === false ) {
      // Bind the global event handler to the element
       if ( elem.addEventListener ) {
             elem.addEventListener( type, eventHandle, false );

        } else if ( elem.attachEvent ) {
             elem.attachEvent( "on" + type, eventHandle );
        }
 }
```

And there you have it! :) I hope it answered both your questions. You can link up to the **non-minified** versions of jquery source and step through it to figure things out. IMO sometimes IE9's debugger is more intuitive (that's the only thing I use it for), and use the pages I've mentioned to browse through the source sanely.

Comment: ok, I know your enthusiastic and all.. but... I hate to break it but out of everyone who answered this, you're the least closest one.. I think you misunderstood my question.

Comment: I wasn't asking how jQuery sets up events, but the 'metadata' within jQuery/JavaScript that stores these connections... @Tom Tu and nomulous are pretty much there... so you seem smart and maybe you can help me out? :)

Comment: ie: var contentWithButtons = $('body').html(); $('body').html(contentWithButtons); ...well, what this does is it destroys my events (in the context of me using Backbone.js's views to set them up). It's not really the library but I think it's JavaScript itself that has the behavior as the other answerers put it..

Comment: @JanCarloViray Sorry, I guess I did mis-understand. It finally boils down to `element.addEventListener`. See this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qu9bF/1/ The listener is cleared when you replace the body content. So I'm assuming this is at the **js implementation/browser** level, elements and their relation with listeners are stored somewhere on the DOMelements themselves.

Comment: Yep, checked the [specs too](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-registration) , event targets can be elements, so it looks like each element at the browser level maintains  which function to call etc.

Comment: nevertheless, thanks for all the extra effort :) you seem enthusiastic about this, so keep it up!

Comment: the other folks aren't really expanding on their answers (even though they both got it somewhat right) so if you revise yours and make it tied to the question then i'll make yours the answer..

Comment: Don't look at how it's done in 1.4.2 unless you plan to stick with it - it has changed a lot since then and it is much smarter in jQuery 1.7 - jQuery will now hold the reference to the event handler in it's cache object and if not cleaned properly either automatically with one of the DOM manipulation methods from jQuery or manually by the programmer using the $.cleanData method you will create a reference which will hold the piece of DOM tree and all the events bound to it in memory and create a leak

Comment: @JanCarloViray updated answer. @TomTu ah thanks, yea I was wonder where `cache` went, I used 1.4.2 because the jq deconstructed page wasn't updated, even there I couldn't just link up to individual lines of source. Yep, implementation is very different in 1.7

Comment: gideon I think it's obvious that @Tom Tu deserves this one.. great insights from him.. we both definitely learned something from that guy. let's give it to him.

Answer (score 2):

Regular events like click or submit (when not bound by jQuery) are actually just properties ('onclick', 'onsubmit') of the DOM elements themselves.

For jQuery events, the library keeps it's own record when you bind them and looks at it when you trigger them. jQuery puts all data about elements in a standard place, which you can access with `$(e).data()`. For events, it's just `$(e).data('events')`.

You can unbind jQuery events with `$().unbind()`, and regular events using the `delete` keyword to delete the object's property which corresponds to the given event.

Comment: That's not what jQuery does for "click" etc.

Comment: I know, but for regular events that's how it works. If you'd read my answer, instead of just downvoting it so yours would succeed, you'd see that I say later that jQuery events work differently.

Comment: this is actually a pretty close answer.. +1 to counter the -1.. just a question, can you clarify "Regular events like click or submit (when not bound by jQuery) are actually just properties ('onclick', 'onsubmit') of the DOM elements themselves?"

Comment: @Jan: The downvote probably comes from the "actually just properties ('onclick', 'onsubmit') of the DOM elements themselves" because that's not true. jQuery will be using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) behind the scenes, using `onclick` and related attributes is about a decade out of date.

Comment: @muistooshort yeah you're right.. I have compassion to those with <1000 reps like me and he said some interesting stuff on 2nd & 3rd paragraphs..  ok, upvoting your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery keeps its own map of element event handlers. There's rarely, very rarely, cause to worry about this unless you're abusing the library somehow.